# Exiting procedure that has called a different procedure VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, procedure

I have a procedure that does some error checking for me and is called from a different procedure. What I want to be able to do is that if incorrect data has been entered and the error checking procedure finds this then I want to stop the procedure that called the error checking procedure. i.e. if error checking procedure is

```
sub errorCheck
```

and main procedure is

```
sub main
```

and main calls error checking. when error is found I want sub errorCheck to stop main. I have tried to use exit sub but this exits only the errorCheck sub not main

and help would be great thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it a function that returns a Boolean. Check if the value is False in the calling procedure main and then do an Exit Sub in the main procedure.

A bit nastier way to do it: Just type End instead of Exit Sub. This does however stop the execution of the code completely.

Something like this:

```
Function errorcheck() As Boolean
' in this case it is always false of course
    errorcheck = False
End Function

Sub main()
    If Not errorcheck Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ye i dont want to end the code. if i return a boolean how do i check in the main procedure if it is true or false? sorry im new to VBA

Answer (score 0):

You can use global object `Err` to complete this task.

Look at the example below:

```
Sub main()

    '(...)

    On Error Resume Next
    Call errorChecking
    If VBA.Err.Number = 999 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    '(...)

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub errorChecking()

    If Error Then
        Call VBA.Err.Raise(999, "errorChecking", "Error found")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Before we invoke function `errorChecking` we instruct VBA that it shouldn't stop if any error occurs - it should just ignore it and go to the next line of code instead.

Inside `errorChecking` function there is a conditional statement that checks if error occurred.
In case the error occurred, this function raise a new error with the number defined by you (999 in my example, you can come up with your own number).

Back in the `Main` function we check if the current number of `VBA.Err` object is 999. If it is, it means the error was raised by the function `errorChecking` and we can leave the `Main` sub.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example based on *Tom's* answer:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim rng As Range, CellIsNogood As Boolean
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter range", Type:=8)
    Call ErrorCheck(rng, CellIsNogood)
    If CellIsNogood Then
        MsgBox "error in range"
    End If
End Sub

Sub ErrorCheck(r As Range, b As Boolean)
    Dim rr As Range
    b = False
    For Each rr In r
        If IsError(rr.Value) Then
            b = True
        End If
    Next rr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing what Tom and had said I did a bit of research and got this working. Below is the code that I used. Thanks for the other answers :)

```
Private Function errorCheckingBox(box1, message) As Boolean
If Len(box1.value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox message, vbExclamation, "Invalid Selection" ' displays a messgae box
    box1.SetFocus
    errorCheckingBox = True
End If
End Function
```